# Invalid python path when configuring VS Code's python virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, python-venv, unc

My goal is to use the VS Code's python debugger with a venv under a UNC path. I've tried setting the default interpreter path (settings.json) and also the debugger's python path (launch.json). The path is in the format of: `\\dfsname\subfolder\tools\venv\Scripts\python.exe`

But I keep getting the error message: `The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid`.

Notes:

- I've been providing the full UNC path because I don't have permission to create a mapped drive.
- My venv exists outside my workspace/script folder (we use a global venv for our python projects)

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of the error and the logs from Output > Python panel?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code requires the slashes to be in the other direction in its configuration files. Everything worked when I set the path to be in the format of: `//dfsname/subfolder/tools/venv/Scripts/python.exe`.

Comment: Backslashes are normally only used on Windows Paths, as far as I am aware.